# Stationary Distribution Defined Differently In a Textbook (Clarification on Definition of subscripts of $mu$)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stationary-processes

for a stationary distribution, I am familiar with the interpretation that the stationary distribution: $\mu$ is the distribution satisfying:

$$\mu=\mu*P$$

However, there is a different characterization I just came across which has a bit of ambiguous notation. In this characterization, $\mu$ solves the following:

$$\mu_j=\sum_{i}\mu_iP_{ij}\quad \forall j$$

My confusion is with the subscripts of $\mu$. Are these meant to denote the $P({X_t}=j)$? If so, then what does the summation over 'i' imply: is that only relative to the position in the transition matrix ie summation across every row of P? In that case $\mu_i$ seems like it would be constant which would make for an odd choice of variable. So I'm guessing now that $m_i$ must be referencing something else or the book chose an oddly convoluted subscript.

Any help interpreting this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i think it's just how you express a matrix multiplication?

Comment: I understood as much, but $\mu_j$ would have to reference a point internal to the vector $\mu$, so that means it has a specific definition in terms of probability

Comment: im a bit confused, these two equations are equivalent no?

Comment: Yes, but there was a bit of ambiguity in the definition which I wanted to make sure I was understanding. Subscripts on stationary distributions mean that you want the probability of a the chain taking on a value but it seems like these subscripts were in relation to $\mu$ as a vector. After playing with it in the 2-state case I realize that they are simultaneously using the subscript to denote that but also solve the system of equations. I see its just a consequence of linear algebra to set up a system of equations with the usual definition of the stationary distributions.